# Combine Objects Within an Array that Share the Same Value for Multiple Keys

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
[
{"a": a, "b": b, "c": c}, 
{"a": a, "b": b, "d": d}, 
{"a": a, "b": 2, "c": 3}
]
```

and I want to combine the first two objects because they have the same value for a and b into one, so that I will have a resulting array:

```
[
{"a": a, "b": b, "c": c, "d": d}, 
{"a": a, "b": 2, "c": 3}
]
```

Could someone help me figure out how to do this in pure JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: the third object also shares the same keys `a` & `b`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Comment: Hi, sorry i meant that the keys share the same value for a and b. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```js
const array = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 4},
    {"a": 1, "b": 3, "d": 5},
    {"a": 2, "b": 2, "c": 3}
];

const combine = (array) => {

    const other = [];
    let combined = {};

    array.forEach((item) => {

        if (!combined.a) combined = item;

        else if (combined.a === item.a && combined.b === item.b) Object.assign(combined, item);

        else other.push(item);
    });

    return other.concat(combined);
};

console.log(combine(array));
```